# Pygame: Drawing a circle after input

Tags: python, input, drawing

this seemed like a really simple code, this is why I'm even more confused that it won't work. I'm creating a game that draws different lines of a picture and, after each shape, asks the user what it could be. My problem is that it won't even draw the first circle once I have the input()-part included, but without the input, it works perfectly fine.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('PyDoodle')
clock= pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(30)
#importing background pictures:
backPimg = pygame.image.load('Wood.jpg')
backPimg = pygame.image.load('Paper.jpg')
backWx = 0
backWy = 0
backPx = 250
backPy = 0
screen.blit(backWimg, (backWx, backWy))
screen.blit(backPimg, (backPx, backPy))

#colors
black = (0, 0, 0)

#solutions
snowman = ('snowman'.capitalize(), 'snow man'.upper(), 'snowman', 'snow man')

#MAIN GAME
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get()
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()

#DRAWING #1: SNOWMAN
#circle 1 - the part that's getting on my nerves
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (500,400), 70, 2)
    guess1 = raw_input('Your guess:\n')
```

It'd be really nice if you could have a look at it, maybe you have some suggestions.

Comment: You are missing a colon after `for event in pygame.event.get()`. Also I can reproduce the problem, although I do not know a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that `pygame` does not receive any events while `raw_input` is waiting for input. (You are not in the event-loop at that point.) As a result you never execute `pygame.display.update()`.

Add `pygame.display.update()` after `pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (500,400), 70, 2)`. However then if a redraw of the window is necessary it will not be executed until the input is finished still.

Probably you should use input mechanisms provided by `pygame` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fixed the updating, now everything runs normal.

Comment: @user3155220 As I pointed out this will still not do what you want if the window needs a redraw, for example because you moved another window on top of it.